# The difference between operator and method on python set

Tags: python-3.x, set

I want to ask what is the difference between

```
# suppose s1, s2 is set in python
method1: >> s1 | s2
method2: >> s1.union(s2)
```

in Python3

Usage of memory?
Performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's analyze the byte-code.

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("s1 | s2")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s1)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (s2)
              6 BINARY_OR
              7 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("s1.union(s2)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s1)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (union)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (s2)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) we can see that these two forms are equivalent in terms of functionality. A difference is that second case involves attribute lookup and a function call, which has higher overhead in interpreter comparing to simple byte code instruction call.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("s1 | s2", setup="s1=set(); s2=set()", number=1000000)
0.11251183700440137
>>> timeit.timeit("s1.union(s2)", setup="s1=set(); s2=set()", number=1000000)
0.19270662899877777
```

Comment: Obviously :) . Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Both operations are expected to perform in the exact same way; `||` is just a convenience over `set.union`.

In CPython, [`set_union`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1198) (called by `set1.union(set2)`) and [`set_or`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1226) (called by `set1 || set2`) which are the functions that in the end carry out the operation, are practically similar.

The difference (as Lukasz pointed out) and the byte-code shows) is mainly in the fact that one involves an attribute lookup and a function call (entailing argument parsing).

Memory/complexity wise *they are similar*, they both call [`set_update_internal`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L973) in the end.

It's worth pointing out that this isn't probably where you should direct your attention if you're looking to optimize. Also, the overhead of function call & method look-up is completely trumped out and not detectable if the set sizes are somewhat large.